# vba: right align ticklabels of a graph (stacked bar 100%)

Tags: excel, vba, alignment, powerpoint

I have the following problem:
I´m trying to create a chart in PowerPoint using data from Excel.

Everything is working fine, I open PowerPoint, I create a chart

```
Set myChart = ppSlide.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlBarStacked100).Chart
```

Then I copy my data from Excel to the chart (including the text of the items) and at last I want to format the chart (size, Position, Colors ...). Again everything is working fine, the only thing not working is the alignment of the tick labels. They are automatically right-aligned, but if they are too long and need 2 rows, they become centered. But I want them right-aligned.
I know how to change the ticklabels (f.e. to make it bold:

```
myChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Bold = msoTrue
```

but I have no clue how to right-align. I can´t use the macro-recorder, because I can´t find this function in Excel, only in ppt.

Anybody has an idea, how I can do this?

Thanks in advance and sry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the alignment like this:

```
myChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Alignment = xlRight
```

or xlLeft or xlCenter

The Orientation Property of TickLabels (possible values in the XlTickLabelOrientation enumeration) and the TickLabelPosition Property of Axis (possible values in the XlTickLabelPosition enumeration) may also be of interest to you.

**Update 1**

I had a look at the pictures but still cannot write a macro to achieve this. Regarding your comment: No, it is not always possible to do something with VBA that can be done through the user interface, e.g. pasting does not have the same options.

I can propose only two options:

- Store a chart with the good settings somewhere (e.g. in Excel's
  Personal.xls) and when you need a new chart, don't create it but Copy
  this instance and paste it (ActivePresentation.Slides(1).ShapeRange.Paste)
- Save the file as xlsx and manipulate it (unzip and modify the XML) - this won't be easy.

**Update 2**

Yes, chart templates is a great idea. I tried it and it works:

```
myChart.ApplyChartTemplate "...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\TemplateName.crtx"
```

Besides, you may try calling PasteSpecial with different parameters.

Comment: If I do this, the Labels are aligned at the bottom. No idea why :-(

Comment: (as seen in the answer below)

Comment: Well, I think Microsoft did not provide an interface to set this. As a workaround I suggest deleting ticklabels and inserting textboxes or shapes.

Comment: that´s strange. It is possible to do this manually (klick on the extend-symbol in the paragraph-section).

Comment: Hi, sry, I just found your comment. I added 3 Pictures below, which Show how to Change this manually in PowerPoint (sry, only in German). You click in the tab "Home", in the section "Paragraph" (Picture 1). There you can change the alignment from "centered" to "right" (Picture 2). Picture 3 shows the result. If this is working manually, there has to be a way to Change that using vba, right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Copying from Excel does work, but after a few Charts the Programm will Crash. Copying from Excel to PPT seems to be a Problem (the same if you copy paste a data-range from Excel to a ppt-Chart). Saving as xlsx and unzipping and modyfing xml sounds interesting, but exceeds my skills... :-)  But another idea: It's possible to create a user-defined Chart and save it as a Chart template. If I add a new Chart, i could create a my own Chart instead of the 'xlBarStacked100'. Would that work?

Comment: Hi, solved it using a template. Thx a lot for your help!!! And sry @all for the chaos, I didn't know when to use "answer", comment or when to upate my original question... Cheers!

Comment: Yes, i do :-) .

Comment: I mean, next to the answer, on the left side, you can see a number, two arrows and a check mark. If you asked a question, you can accept it with the check mark, if you find an answer useful / not useful, you can up- / downvote it with the arrows, so other users will not have to try all the solutions suggested. Please refer to the info tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi, yes, I did that, a message appeared, that i have too few Reputation Points, so the Rating ist saved, but not displayed.

Comment: ah, now i did :-)

Answer (score 0):

[what happens if i use "myChart.Axes(xlCategory).Ticklabels.Alignment = xlRight":](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7hZj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Picture 1 (Tab "home", section 'Paragraph'), klick at the Symbol in the downright corner:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLNhD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Picture 2: Choose Right-Align instead of 'centered'

[image]